# Everywhere analytic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that the function $f(z)=2^z$ is analytic everywhere (entire).

But I want to know this:  is the function $f(z)=z^z$ analytic ?

Comment: $z^z$ is multivalued so I assume you mean to take the principal value?  But whatever you do, the resulting function won't be analytic.

Comment: It is analytic away from the branch cut of $\log(z)$ you use to construct $z^z$.  It is, in general, not possible to extend the function continuously onto the branch cut, so it is not entire.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(z)=z^z$ is defined as

$$f(z)=e^{z\log(z)}$$

where $\log(z)=\text{Log}(|z|)+i\arg(z)$ is the multivalued complex logarithm and the $\text{Log}$ function is the logarithm from real analysis.

The function $f(z)=z^z$ is multivalued since the argument of $z$, $\arg(z)$, is multivalued and can be written as

$$\arg(z)=\text{Arg}(z)+2n\pi$$

for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $-\pi <\text{Arg}(z)\le  \pi$ is the principal argument of $z$.

Therefore,

$$z^z=e^{\text{Log}(|z|)}e^{i\arg(z)\,z}$$

which is not entire since $\text{Log}(|z|)$ is not defined at the origin and,  moreover, $\text{arg}(z)$ is discontinuous along any chosen branch cut that originates at $\{0\}$ and extends to the point at $\infty$.

For example, if we choose the Principal Branch cut, which is the cut taken along the negative real axis, then $\arg(z)=\text{Arg}(z)+2n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $z^z$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z|\text{Im}(z)=0,\text{Re}(z)\le 0\}$, but not entire due to the discontinuity on the set $\{z|\text{Im}(z)=0,\text{Re}(z)\le 0\}$.

---

Note that $2^z$ is also multivalued with

$$2^z = e^{\text{Log}(2)z}e^{i2n\pi z}$$

*** but for each fixed integer $n$***, the function $2^z=e^{\text{Log}(2)z}e^{i2n\pi z}$ is an entire function.

Comment: Is $e^z$ multivaled also just like $2^z$? What about $t^z$ where $t>0$ is real?

Comment: There is a subtle distinction between the function $e^z$ and $(e)^z$.  The former is the exponential function, which is defiened as $e^z\equiv e^{|z|}(\cos(\arg(z))+i\sin(\arg(z)))$.  The latter is multivalued

Comment: And yet they are both analytic and agree on the real axis.

Comment: So you claim that the functions $f_n(z) := \exp(z+2\pi i n z)$ are not entire but multi-valued? They are the composite of two entire functions, so how could they **not** be analytic? No poles or essential singularities. In detail, let $g_n(z) := (1+2\pi i n)z$ which is a linear function, hence entire, then $f_n(z) :=\exp(g_n(z))$ must be entire also.

Comment: You claim it is discontinuous. Give me an example of a value of $z$ and $n$ where it is discontinuous. I assume you mean $z=0$? You still have not refuted my $f_n$ and $g_n$ proof. The problem with $\log$ is that it is not defined at zero and behaves very badly there. Also if you circle around zero the value changes. That is why get get branches.

Comment: @somos Is $\arg(z)$ continuous?

Comment: Of course $\arg(z)$ is continuous outside of the branch cut, but if you go around zero, it is not the same as before. That is why you need the branch cut. What does this have to do with $\exp(z+2\pi i n z)$ which is a composition of two entire functions and hence entire?

Comment: I already did a long time ago. You **still** refuse to answer my question about $\exp(z +2\pi i n z)$ because it is obvious that it is entire. What is it that you fail to comprehend about that?

Comment: You might as well attempt to prove that $z^n$ has a branch cut because $z^n = \exp(n\log(z))$ involves $\log(z)$ which is multivalued. Of course, it is obvious that $z^n$ is entire for any integer $n>0$ so your reasoning falls apart.

Comment: @somos If $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $z^n$  is entire since $e^{n\log(z)}=e^{n\text{Log}(|z|}e^{in(\text{Arg}(z)+2\pi nk)}=e^{n\text{\Log(|z|)}+in\text{Arg}(z)}$, which is single-valued and can be shown to satisfy the CR equations!

Comment: My authoritative reference is the [DLMF section 4.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.2). It states that "but the general value of $e^z$ is $e^z = (\exp z)\,\exp(2kz\pi i), \; z\in\mathbb{Z}. $" It does not state that there is a branch cut because the function is entire. The only reason it is multivalued is the $\exp(2kz\pi i)$ factor. But there is no reason not to choose the entire principal value.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: You already improved your answer by adding "but for each fixed integer n ... is an entire functio" which is all I wanted to make a point about.Thanks for writing that!

Comment: @somos Yes that was an edit made quite some tine ago.  Pleased we're good now.